# On Glaeser's Theorem for non-smooth functions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smoothness

Glaeser's Theorem says that a $C^\infty$ function $F$ on $\mathbb R^n$ which is invariant under permutation of the variables is a smooth function of the symmetric polynomials of $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$.

Question 1: What remains (if anything) of this statement if $F$ is $C^k$ ?

Question 2: In the statement above, is it clear that you can replace $\mathbb R^n$ by a symmetric open subset of $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Can you provide a reference for Gleaser's theorem?

Comment: For 1), take $F(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)=\sum |x_i|^k$ with $k$ odd.

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970204?origin=crossref&seq=1

Comment: @abx Your example is $C^{k-1}$ and invariant under permutation.  Is it not a $C^{k-1}$ function of the symmetric polynomials?  In the case $n=2$, $k=1$, $|x_1| + |x_2| = \sqrt{(x_1+x_2)^2 - 2 x_1 x_2 + 2 |x_1 x_2|}$.  Or are you just saying it's not a smooth function?

Comment: @Robert Israel: maybe I was too hasty. Do you think you could do that for any $k$?

Comment: @piotr MR188382 26.40
Glaeser, Georges Fonctions composées différentiables. (French) 1963 Séminaire d'Analyse, dirigé par P. Lelong, 1962/63, No. 2 4 pp. Secrétariat mathématique, Paris

Answer (score 9):

A more direct reference (quoted in Rumberger's paper) is: G. Barbançon, *Le théorème de Newton pour les fonctions de classe* $C^r$. Ann. Sci. École Norm. Sup. 5 (1972), 435–458. He proves that a symmetric function  of class $C^{nr}$ on $\Bbb{R}^n$ is a function  of class $C^{r}$ of the symmetric polynomials.

Answer (score 8):

My collegue Armin Rainer pointed me to the following paper, which has some answers, also in its references. There is a loss of differentiability involved.

- Matthias Rumberger: Finitely differentiable invariants. Math. Z. 229, 675–694 (1998)